# Flutter_blue -> Connection error: [onConnectionStateChange] status: 133 newState: 0

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

flutter_blu version: 0.7.3 (also test it with git repo defined into dependecies in pubspec.yaml with same result)
Problem detected on: Samsung Galaxy J6 (Android 10 - API 29) and Huawei P8 Lite (Android 7.0 API 24). Errors are more frequently in Samsung than Huawei.

```
Flutter Doctor info:
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.27.0-4.0.pre, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
• Flutter version 1.27.0-4.0.pre at /Users/sissa/flutter
• Framework revision f8cd24de95 (10 days ago), 2021-02-16 11:24:17 -0800
• Engine revision 1d537824d6
• Dart version 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-30.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
• Android SDK at /Users/sissa/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.2
• ANDROID_HOME = /Users/sissa/Library/Android/sdk
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio 2.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
• CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 2.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.40.0)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension can be installed from:
 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• SM J610FN (mobile) • bbc7a841 • android-arm • Android 10 (API 29)
• iPhone (mobile) • f063d3c4cfd212cac4386163446403a522fa40cb • ios • iOS 14.4
• Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 88.0.4324.192
```

This error occurs on connection action. Scan works correctly. iOS not tested.
Note that: location permissions has granted.

I have tried solve the problem with this solution, but not luck.

This is my connection code:

```
Column(
    children: [
      (vModel.bluetoothManager.deviceState == BluetoothDeviceState.connected &&
                  isSbpUnsynced(sbp: Provider.of<SbpProvider>(context).sbp)) ||
              _mustShowBanner()
          ? SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 12)
          : SizedBox(),
      Expanded(child: pages[currentPageIndex]),
      null != vModel && vModel.bluetoothManager.isScanning
          ? StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
              stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
              initialData: [],
              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                for (var e in snapshot.data) {
                  print('device: ${e.advertisementData.localName}');
                }
                return Column(
                  children: snapshot.data.where((dev) => dev.advertisementData.localName.contains(widget.dev.psn)).map(
                    (r) {
                      vModel.bluetoothManager.stopScan();
                      vModel.setDevice(r); // **_======>>> LAUNCHING CONNECTION PROCESS_**
                      return SizedBox();
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                );
              },
            )
          : SizedBox(),
    ],
  ),

// =======>>> CONNECTION PROCESS ***********
@override
  Future connect({int timeoutDurationInSeconds, Function onTimeOut, Function onConnected, bool stopScanProcess = true}) async {
    try {
      if (stopScanProcess) {
        scanTimeOut?.cancel();
        stopScan();
      }
      resetCharacteristics();

      isConnecting = true;
      //checkState();
      await checkCurrentState();

      await deviceToConnect
          .connect(autoConnect: false)
          .timeout(
            Duration(seconds: kBleTimeoutConn),
            onTimeout: () => onTimeOut(),
          )
          .then(
        (value) async {
          await checkCurrentState();

          if (deviceState == BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
            connectionSetup(onConnected: onConnected);
          }
        },
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
        isConnecting = false;

        print(e);
        throw BluetoothConnectionException();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> checkCurrentState() async {
    if (null != deviceToConnect) {
      await for (BluetoothDeviceState value in deviceToConnect.state) {
        deviceState = value;
        
        return deviceState;
      }
      return null;
    } else
      return null;
  }

@override
  Future disconnect({Function onDisconnected}) async {
    if (null != deviceToConnect) {
      stopScan();

      resetCharacteristics();

      print('disconnecting ${deviceToConnect?.name}');

      await deviceToConnect.disconnect();
      print('************ disconnected');

      isConnecting = false;

      if (null != deviceBluetoothResponseSubscription) deviceBluetoothResponseSubscription.cancel();

      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
      //checkState();
      //await checkCurrentState();
      deviceState = BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected;
    }
    if (null != onDisconnected) onDisconnected();
  }
```

Comment: Does this happen all the time? We get this error occasionally, apparently it's due to a violation of the bluetooth spec by android. https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/33313/android-gatt-133-error

Comment: This problem happen too often. Idon't know how to apply the possible solution suggested on your link in this case because I'm using flutter_blue library package.